# Override Bootstrap SCSS is giving syntax error for darken(color)

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to override Bootstrap with SCSS so I can use my own code for the buttons. Bootstrap has been imported and is located within node_module inside of my project.

I basically want to get ride of the default square shape the button takes and have the background color to my specifications.

I decided to start with color and made my own color to be used instead of the value that Bootstrap relies on in the following format.

```
$button-color: rgba(255, 255, 242, 0);

@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
```

This format I am using based off of the Theming Bootstrap page in the [Importing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/) section.

```
Argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color
```

I looked this up on the website and noticed those that received this error had actually attempted to use this darken($color, $amount) format. I did not and I am not sure how to resolve this issue because I am not using it.

Comment: Is that related to: "Method overriding, in object oriented programming, is a language feature that allows a subclass or child class to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its superclasses or parent classes."

Comment: @curiousguy I don't think so, I just want to use my own styling with Sass and not Bootstraps

Comment: Then don't use the **override** tag that's specifically about OO programming and function overriding in derived classes.

Comment: Sorry about that, I removed it. Thank you for pointing that out to me @curiousguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the _functions SASS file too...

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a follow up question so I can understand your solution better. Is the option B under that section stating that I would need to at minimum import variables, functions and mixins? I suppose when I initially read it, I thought that those 3 were only required for specific instances.

Comment: `_variables` depends on `_functions` so they must be used together. You only need to import `_mixins` if your overrides include use of mixins. In your case it does not.